# Not Able to De-serialize JSON

Tags: apex, lightning

I am not able to convert the  JSON string into List of sObject.

Lightning Controller:

```
createOwner : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('$$$$$$Test: '+ component.get("v.ownerList"));
    var action = component.get("c.createAdditionalOwner");
    var ARLIlistAsString = JSON.stringify(component.get("v.ownerList"));
    action.setParams({
        "newOwnerList": ARLIlistAsString

    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log('$$$$$Check: '+ response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Apex Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String createAdditionalOwner(String newOwnerList){
    System.debug('$$$$$Check: '+ newOwnerList);
    List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c> newOwnerList2 = (List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c>)JSON.deserialize(newOwnerList, Visit_Owner_Institution__c.class);
    System.debug('$$$$$Check: '+ newOwnerList2);
    return 'Success';

}
```

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="ownerList" type="Visit_Owner_Institution__c[]"/>
```

Comment: You want to deserialize it as a list, not an individual object, right? Make sure you are only using the List class, not the object class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert a list into a single record, then back in to a list:

```
List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c> newOwnerList2 = (List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c>)
    JSON.deserialize(newOwnerList, Visit_Owner_Institution__c.class);
```

---

Generally speaking, when using JSON.deserialize, you want to use the following format:

> **T** result = (**T**)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, **T**.class);

Where **T** is a specific type of class. In your code, however, **T** is correct in the first two places, but not in the third. All three **T** values should be exactly `List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c>`.

---

```
List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c> newOwnerList2 = (List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c>)
    JSON.deserialize(newOwnerList, List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c>.class);
```